# Find primary language of a movie in Freebase

Tags: freebase

I am using Freebase to access details of movies. I am mainly interested in retrieving the language the movie was primarily released in (not dubbed languages). However, the /film/film/language property gives all the languages the movie was released in.

For eg. for the page on Titanic: http://www.freebase.com/m/0dr_4, if you check the Languages (/film/film/language) property, you will see six values: English, Swedish, Italian, French, German, Russian. Titanic was primarily an English language movie - other languages were dubbed versions.

How do I retrieve the value of the primary language of the movie only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that you are using is the correct one and it should only return the original language(s) of the film, but it has apparently been (incorrectly) populated with languages of all the releases.

It's likely that the first value is the original language of the movie, so you could try just using that.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to resort to more sophisticated heuristics (or wait for the data to be fixed).

Comment: Actually the description of that property says "all languages spoken in the film". So if a film is in English, and has even one sentence in French, say, I suppose the property will contain "French". Not sure this is the cause of "pollution". If it is, however, then another assumption we're making here is that the languages are sorted according to "what % of sentences are spoken in that language" or something similar.